# Magento optimisation : Compilation and Use Flat Catalog Product Features

Tags: magento-1.9, compilation

I would like to improve the performance of my Magento website.

After checking online, it seems that I can:
- Set Use Flat Catalog Product to YES
- Enable the Compilation Tool

I will do a Cpanel backup before running these changes.

Question: Can these modifications break my website ?

---

The one in System > Tools > Compilation.
http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/system-operations/system-tools-compilation.html

Answer (score 2):

Magento typically stores catalog data in multiple tables, based on the Entity-Attribute-Value (EAV) model. Because product attributes are stored in many tables, SQL queries are sometimes long and complex.

In contrast, a flat catalog creates new tables on the fly, where each row contains all the necessary data about a product or category. A flat catalog is updated automatically—either every minute, or according to your cron job. Flat catalog indexing can also speed up the processing of catalog and cart price rules.

After you enable the Flat Catalog you have to run the reindex command.
This will not break your site.

Comment: Thank you so much. And what about the compilation tool? Thanks

Comment: What compilation tool you are talking about ?

Comment: Sorry I am not aware of compilation tool in Magento 1.